# JSON Java put() return String, not void? put() not working!! ;((

Tags: java, json

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;

class Edit_Details_OnlyAdmin_Loop {

    public void Edit_Details_OnlyAdmin_Loop_main(int Option, String newVal, String credUserName, String credPwd) {
        try {
            JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();

            JSONArray a = (JSONArray) parser.parse(new FileReader(Main.databasepath));
            // System.out.println("a is"+a);

            switch (Option) {
                case 1:
                    for (Object o : a) {
                        // System.out.println("o is"+o);

                        JSONObject User = (JSONObject) o;
                        // System.out.println("user is:" + User);

                        String Username = (String) User.get("Username");
                        String Pwd = (String) User.get("Password");
                        // JSONObject new1= (JSONObject) User.get("Name");
                        if (credUserName.equals(Username) && credPwd.equals(Pwd)) {
                            // System.out.println(User.remove("Name"));
                            User.put("Name", newVal);
                            // System.out.println("updated successfully");

                        }

                    }
                    break;
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

above code, inside the for loop, the json .put() i had tried to system print the .put and return a value instead of a void function...
**i just want to replace my value inside the json file using the .put()...**
all the parameter passed is correct, been checked one by one

below is my database file

```
[{"Role":"1","AssesType":"","Username":"","Module":"","Marks":"","Name":"q","Password":"123","Programme":""},{"Role":"3","AssesType":"1","Username":"tp054660","Module":"2","Marks":"","Name":"yaphanyee","Password":"123","Programme":"1"},{"Role":"3","AssesType":"2","Username":"tp054660","Module":"2","Marks":"","Name":"yaphanyee","Password":"123","Programme":"1"},{"Role":"1","AssesType":"","Username":"jsn","Module":"","Marks":"","Name":"jason","Password":"123","Programme":""},{"Role":"1","AssesType":"","Username":"123","Module":"","Marks":"","Name":"tp054660","Password":"123","Programme":""}]
```

above code demonstrate the effort of changing the value stored as key 'Name' and replace with new input data....

and the put() is not working as expected, too there is no any catch error

Comment: I don't really understand your question. put returns the value, it's not necessary a String

Comment: "the put() is not working as expected" ... because it works and doesn't throw an error? What are you expecting from it?

Comment: What is "Option"?

Comment: @Stultuske helo stultuske, the put function is not working, that it didnt replace the value inside the json object
question is, the put() is not working and how to solve it.. appreciated

Comment: @Stultuske i expect that my database object, the value will be replaced and updated to new one

Comment: option is just another function ,where user can choose to edit which attribute in the object. option i passed number 1 for switch case, so user could update their value keyed "Name" in the json object

Comment: @HanYeeYap An object cannot be assigned to a switch statement. Only primitive datatypes and String

Comment: @Reporter nono, the thing passed into the switch statement is just an integer, pass from outer layer function. am i got u right? or i  misunderstood

Comment: as per documentation put() does not any value.As per my understanding your are saying it is return value. How it is possible?

Comment: @Developer arggg, i dont really get it ... i wish the put() could update one of the values inside the json object..
for the comments "does not any value", what does it mean,,,

Comment: @HanYeeYap can you please try what sina is saying?

Comment: or is there any ways that can update json file? i been go through almost all question in stack overflow and still cant solve...

Comment: @HanYeeYap and why would you expect that? You basically just put a value in a local Map, nothing more.

Comment: @Stultuske hmm.. ya i read the documentation and saw the .put() is a local map, am i right?
i meant, i could teamviewer now if you all should, really a rookie in java..

Comment: @HanYeeYap no. the put is a method of the map which you call, and which stores the value into the local map (in your code, called: User). Just because you call .put doesn't mean there is any interaction with the database

Comment: @Stultuske hmm, so what should i do i wanna update the attributes inside? ie 
"Name":"yaphanyee" to "Name":"hanyeeyap"

Comment: actually write them to the database. I assume you know something about persistence frameworks?

Comment: @Stultuske idk about that framework... im still struggling which code to be inserted in order to have the updated information access to the database.sjson...

Comment: that would be ... a persistence framework. JPA, hibernate, ... it's not a two line fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write your changed JSON data to disk if you want to see any actual changes in your file.

Use a code similar to the following (I'm not completely sure about some of your datatypes, so there might be slight compile errors):

```
try (FileWriter file = new FileWriter(Main.databasepath)) {
    file.write(a.toJSONString());
    file.flush();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: hi @sina, i had tried and all i realised is that it wiped out the entire file into blank..

Comment: Please add that code to your question because that is where your error likely was. You will not be able to see a change in the file unless you write it to disk. The code you posted so far looks fine (except that you don't write to disk).

Comment: hi sina, i got it now. i dont have any step to accessing with the file, right? then i ughhh, need to add what

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your comment. Can you please try and explain it again?

Comment: i solved it successfully, sina, thanks and i love u, lots of appreciation to be shown,..

Comment: just now i use file write but forgot add the attribute into the write()